# AS3 Cannot access stage from custom class

Tags: actionscript-3, sprite, stage

How can I access the stage and especially the width and mouse position of the flash Movie from a custom class?

```
package classes
{
   import flash.events.*;
   import flash.display.*;

   public class TableManager extends Sprite
   {
        public function TableManager() {
            sayStage();
        }
        public function sayStage():void 
        {
            trace(stage);
        }
  }   
}
```

This will only return nill. I know that DisplayObjects don't have any stage until they have been initiated so you can't access the stage in your constructor but even if I call sayStage() later as an instance method it won't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

If TableManager is on the stage you can access the stage with `this.stage`.

The trick is you have to wait for the instance to be added to the stage. You can listen for the `ADDED_TO_STAGE` event so you know when that's happened.

```
package classes {
import flash.events.*;
import flash.display.*;

public class TableManager extends Sprite {
    public function TableManager() {
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
    }

    private function onAddedToStage(e:Event):void {
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
        sayStage();
    }

    public function sayStage():void {
        trace(this.stage);
    }
}   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The most defensive way to write this is:

```
public function TableManager() {
    if(this.stage) init();
    else this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
}

private function init(e:Event = null):void {
    if(e != null) this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    sayStage();
}
```

If the object is already on the stage at the time of initialization, then immediately call the `init` function with no arguments. If not wait until its been added to the stage. Then when the `init` function gets called, if it was called as the result of an event, then detach the event handler, and move along.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a reference of the root movieclip (i.e. the stage) to your custom class.

e.g.

```
package classes
{
   import flash.events.*;
   import flash.display.*;

   public class TableManager extends Sprite
   {
       private var _rootMC:MovieClip; 

       public function TableManager(rootMC:MovieClip) {
            _rootMC = rootMC;
            sayStage();
        }
        public function sayStage():void 
        {
            trace(_rootMC.stage);
            trace(_rootMC.stage.stageWidth);
        }
  }   
}
```

Then when instantiating your instance of TableManager from the root timeline:

```
//the keyword 'this' is the root movieclip.
var newTM:TableManager = new TableManager(this);
```

Comment: In my case I need to initiate the class from another class

Answer (score 0):

`stage` will be null as long as the `Sprite` hasn't been added to the display list - it's nothing to do with initiation. E.g.

```
var t:TableManager = new TableManager;
stage.addChild( t ); // or your root class, or any class that's already on the displaylist
trace( t.stage ); // [Stage stage]
t.parent.removeChild( t );
trace( t.stage ); // null
```

As @crooksy88 suggests, either pass in the stage to the constructor, or keep it as a static somewhere, say your main document class, so that you can access it everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

i think usefull for You should be create static reference to stage :

in Your main class add line and set stage :

```
public static var stage:Stage;
...
public function Main():void { // constructor
     Main.stage = stage;
     ...
```

and than in custom class :

```
public function sayStage():void 
        {
            trace(Main.stage);
            trace(Main.stage.stageWidth);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you may access this.stage when the current object(also a sprite) is already attached to the stage.

```
public class TableManager extends Sprite{
    public function TableManager()
    {
    }
    public function sayStage():void 
    {
        trace(stage);
    }
}
TableManager tm=new TableManager();
//tm.sayStage();  // no
addChild(tm);  
tm.sayStage();  // fine
```

hope this could help

Answer (score 0):

here is a pretty good solution you only need to reference the stage inside your class you just pass it as a simple object, here how to do that

```
package  {

    public class Eventhndl{

        private var obj:Object;

        public function Eventhndl(objStage:Object):void{
            obj = objStage;

            trace(obj); // now the obj variable is a reference to the stage and you can work as normal you do with stage (addChild, Events Etc..)

        }

}
```

this is how you make instance to run it, i have used the constructor method but you can change it to any function as you wish and call it whenever you need it.

```
import Eventhndl;

var EH:Eventhndl = new Eventhndl(stage);
```

here is some few Examples how to access stage from class

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40691908/1640362

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40691325/1640362